# Defining a variable in C/C++ to Scilab

Tags: c++, c, scilab

I have a Visual Studio C++ project, and a [Scilab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab) **.sce** file. I want to execute this file from my C++ project, and this could be done with:

```
  ........
  SendScilabJob("exec('U:/scilab/done/SNR.sce');");
 ......
```

To keep the question simple, the execution succeeded, but when I get this:

```
 The package IPD (8.3-2) is already loaded
 The package SIVP (0.5.3-3) is already loaded
```

on my console it just don't work without giving any error message. By the way, I'm using both packages in my Scilab code.

When everything works fine, I get this:

```
 Start IPD - Image Processing Design
    Load macros
    Load dependencies
    Load gateways

 SIVP - Scilab Image and Video Processing Toolbox
    Load macros
    Load gateways
```

Comment: Have a look into the SNR.sce file: is IDP or SIVP mentioned there? Can you remove that?

Comment: no I can't it a script that use both of them

Comment: What i am trying to say is that maybe the .sce file tries to include the packages. If you are loading them before you are exec'ing the .sce and the .sce tries to load them again, that might explain the error.

Comment: No because when it work I loaded them too but I get smt else (see the question edit)